# How can we use suiteScript(netsuite 2.0) in Node JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, netsuite, suitescript

We need to get the field from the NetSuite Record page, i.e. workOrder.
I've created a single JS file that defines the pageInit function and where I'm getting the xyz field value.

I'd like to have the NetSuite xyz field locally in the console so I can use it in my Java-script code to make it dynamic.

But here, I am unable to get an exact solution for it.
How can we get the value of a netsuite (work-order page) form field using lambda and Node.js?

Comment: You can only use the SuiteScript API within the NetSuite environment. If you want to access values from an external environment like Node.js (AWS), you'll have to write a RESTlet API (with SuiteScript), which you can access through token based authorization.

Comment: or you can use the SuiteTalk REST Web Services API: https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/book_1559132836.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything in your question that requires node so far. If you really need to use node you should look at the RESTlet/SuiteTalk options mentioned in the comments.

If you are wanting to run a script in the console the code below shows how to do that.

I keep a folder of these for various admin tasks. Just open a console and run when needed. The code below is fairly complex for one of these scripts (though not the most complex by far). It is used while editing a role. It presents a list of roles that have been set up with minimal permissions for a particular job function. The roles that are selected have their permissions applied to the currently being edited role.

`N/currentRecord` is the API that loads the current record's data.

```js
require(['N/search', 'N/currentRecord', 'N/xml'], function(search, currentRecord, xml) {

    const roleList = search.create({
        type:'role',
        filters:[
            ['custrecord_kotn_is_role_capabilities', 'is', 'T'], 'AND',
            ['isinactive', 'is', 'F']
        ],
        columns:['name']
    }).run().getRange({start:0, end:1000}).map(ref=>{
        return {
            id:ref.id,
            name:ref.getValue({name:'name'})
        };
    }).map(r=>(`<option value=${r.id}>${r.name}</option>`)).join('\n');

    console.log(roleList);

    const body = document.querySelector('body');

    

    const form=`
        <div id="kotn-choose-roles" style="position:fixed;width:320px;left:50%;transform:translateX(-50%);top:30vh;background-color:white;border:1px solid #ccc;padding:10px;">
        <form onSubmit="return false;">
        <table><tr>
            <td>Roles</td>
            <td><select multiple id="kotn-roles-chosen">${roleList}</select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><button id="kotn-apply-roles" type="button">Apply</button><button id="kotn-cancel-roles" type="button">Cancel</button>
        </table>
        </form>
        </div>
    `;

    const frag = document.createElement('div');
    frag.setAttribute('id', 'kotn-role-chooser');
    frag.innerHTML = form;

    body.appendChild(frag);

    jQuery('#kotn-apply-roles').bind('click', function(){
        const roleIds = jQuery('#kotn-roles-chosen').val();
        console.log(roleIds);
        applyRoles(roleIds);
        alert('done');

        frag.parentNode.removeChild(frag);
    });

    jQuery('#kotn-cancel-roles').bind('click', function(){
        frag.parentNode.removeChild(frag);
    });


    function applyRoles(permSources){

        const roleRec = currentRecord.get();

        const machineNames = [
            {
                name:'custrecordmach',
                permRef:'custrecord',
                permLevelField:'permittedlevel',
                restricted:'restriction'
            },

            {
                name:'tranmach',
                permRef: 'permkey1',
                permLevelField:'permlevel1'
            },
            {
                name:'listsmach',
                permRef:'permkey3',
                permLevelField:'permlevel3'
            },
            {
                name:'setupmach',
                permRef:'permkey4',
                permLevelField:'permlevel4'
            }

        ];

        function doPerms(){
            if(!permSources.length) return;
            processPerm(permSources.shift()).then(doPerms);
        }

        function processPerm(id){
            return fetchWithRetry(`/app/setup/role.nl?id=${id}&xml=T`,{
                credentials: 'same-origin'
            }).
                then(resp =>{
                    console.log(id, resp.status);
                    return resp.text();
                }).
                then(data=>{


                    const roleDoc = xml.Parser.fromString({
                        text: data
                    });

                    console.log('role: ',selectValue(roleDoc, '/nsResponse/record/name'));

                    machineNames.forEach(m=>{
                        console.log('process machine', `//machine[@name="${m.name}"]/line`);
                        const docLines = xml.XPath.select({
                            node: roleDoc,
                            xpath: `//machine[@name="${m.name}"]/line`
                        });

                        console.log('machine lines', m.name, docLines.length);

                        const lines = docLines.map(line=>{

                            const perm = {
                                perm: selectValue(line, m.permRef),
                                level:parseInt(selectValue(line, m.permLevelField),10),
                                restricted:null
                            };
                            if(m.restricted){
                                perm.restricted = parseInt(selectValue(line, m.restricted), 10);
                            }
                            return perm;
                        });

                        console.log('lines for', m.name, lines);

                        const findPermIndex = perm =>{
                            for(var i = 0; i< lines.length; i++){
                                if(lines[i].perm == perm) return i;
                            }
                            return -1;
                        };

                        iter(roleRec, m.name, (idx, getV) =>{
                            const perm = getV(m.permRef);
                            const applyingIndex = findPermIndex(perm);
                            if(applyingIndex == -1) return;

                            const applyingPerm = lines.splice(applyingIndex, 1)[0];

                            console.log('have current perm', JSON.stringify(applyingPerm));

                            const permVal = getV(m.permLevelField);
                            const applyingLevel = (permVal >= applyingPerm.level) ? permVal : applyingPerm.level;

                            let applyingRestriction = null;

                            if(m.restricted){
                                let restrictionVal = parseInt(getV(m.restricted), 10) || null;
                                applyingRestriction = (!restrictionVal) ? null : applyingPerm.restricted;

                                if(restrictionVal && applyingRestriction){
                                    if(applyingRestriction <restrictionVal){
                                        applyingRestriction = restrictionVal;
                                    }
                                } 
                            }

                            setTimeout(()=>{

                                roleRec.selectLine({sublistId:m.name, line:idx});
                                roleRec.setCurrentSublistValue({sublistId:m.name, fieldId:m.permLevelField, value:applyingLevel, forceSyncSourcing:true});
                                if(applyingRestriction){
                                    roleRec.setCurrentSublistValue({sublistId:m.name, fieldId:m.restricted, value:applyingRestriction, forceSyncSourcing:true});
                                }
                                roleRec.commitLine({sublistId:m.name});
                            }, idx *20);

                            
                        });
                        lines.forEach((line, idx)=>{
                            console.log('adding ', m.name, JSON.stringify(line));
                            setTimeout(()=>{
                                roleRec.selectNewLine({sublistId:m.name});
                                roleRec.setCurrentSublistValue({sublistId:m.name, fieldId:m.permRef, value:line.perm, forceSyncSourcing:true});
                                roleRec.setCurrentSublistValue({sublistId:m.name, fieldId:m.permLevelField, value:line.level, forceSyncSourcing:true});
                                if(m.restricted){
                                    roleRec.setCurrentSublistValue({sublistId:m.name, fieldId:m.restricted, value:line.restricted, forceSyncSourcing:true });
                                }
                                roleRec.commitLine({sublistId:m.name, ignoreRecalc:true});
                            }, idx*100);
                        });
                    });
                    return id;
                }).catch(e=>{
                    console.error(e.message);
                    return null;
                });
        }

        doPerms();
    }



    //load role
    //for each machine
    //  transfer perms
    //  check current level - use highest



    function selectValue(node, path) {
        const targets = xml.XPath.select({
            node: node,
            xpath: path
        });

        if (!targets || !targets.length) return null;
        return targets[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
    }

    // function selectAttribute(node, path, attr) {
    //  const targets = xml.XPath.select({
    //      node: node,
    //      xpath: path
    //  });

    //  if (!targets || !targets.length) return null;
    //  return targets[0].getAttribute(attr);
    // }

    function iter(rec, listName, cb){
        var lim = rec.getLineCount({sublistId:listName});
        var i = 0;
        var getV = function (fld){
            return rec.getSublistValue({sublistId:listName, fieldId:fld, line:i});
        };
        for(; i< lim; i++){
            cb(i, getV);
        }
    }



    async function fetchWithRetry(url, opts, tries = 3) {
        const errs = [];

        const waiter = async (pause) => {
            return new Promise(resolve => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    resolve(null);
                }, pause);
            });
        };


        for (let i = 0; i < tries; i++) {
            // log for illustration
            if(i != 0) console.error(`trying GET '${url}' [${i + 1} of ${tries}]`);

            try {
                const resp = await fetch(url, opts);
                return resp;
            } catch (err) {
                errs.push(err);
                await waiter(800 * i + 1);
            }
        }

        throw errs;
    }


});
```